# Is it possible to send push notification from OneSignal to Harmony OS?

Tags: mobile, push-notification, onesignal, huawei-mobile-services, harmonyos

We will make an application which will run on Harmony OS devices, so is it possible to send push notifications from OneSignal to any Harmony OS devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, OneSignal does not support Harmony OS right now.

they support Huawei Push Kit on Android devices only, so you can publish your Android App on Huawei's App Gallery.

Comment: So, how can we send push notifications to Harmony OS Devices?

Comment: You can use [Huawei push kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-pushkit/)